# PHP: Using one portion of a multidimensional object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I am using an API to return synonyms for a given word. For example, for the word "funny", I have returned:

```
Array ( [adjective] => stdClass Object ( [syn] => Array ( [0] => amusing [1] => comic [2] => comical [3] => laughable [4] => mirthful [5] => risible [6] => curious [7] => odd [8] => peculiar [9] => queer [10] => rum [11] => rummy [12] => singular [13] => fishy [14] => shady [15] => suspect [16] => suspicious ) [sim] => Array ( [0] => humorous [1] => humourous [2] => ill [3] => questionable [4] => sick [5] => strange [6] => unusual ) ) [noun] => stdClass Object ( [syn] => Array ( [0] => funny story [1] => good story [2] => funny remark [3] => gag [4] => jape [5] => jest [6] => joke [7] => laugh ) ) )
```

The thing is, I only need to find the synonyms, which in this case would be:

```
print_r($synonyms->adjective->syn);
```

The problem is that the word may not alway be an "adjective", so it may change to something like:

```
$synonyms->noun->syn;
```

How to I bypass the first level of this object and just use something like:

```
$synonyms->syn; // I only want the synonyms
```

.... something that would work no matter what type of word it is?

The format will always be `$synonyms->type_of_word->syn;`

Comment: Is there a pre-defined list of word types? If so, what are they?

Comment: @Dan There is not a list, at least that I know of.

Comment: if you notice your API output, funny can also be a noun. How will you decide which synonyms you want unless you specify the word type?

Comment: FWIW, That's a pretty poor API. `adjective` should not be a property name, it should be the value of a property that is named `partOfSpeech`. Gotta hate bad design.

Comment: If there is an API call to also check word type returned then you could use that variable to get your synonyms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just walk through the `$synonyms` array and for each key (type_of_word) you can check if it has `syn` peer. I don't know if, in case of more types have `syn` defined, you want to merge them all into the result or take just the first one, but you can easily modify the snippet below (it will merge all synonyms from all peers that have `syn` defined):

```
$result = array();
foreach ($synonyms as $type) {
    if (isset($type->syn)) {
        $result = array_merge($result, $type->syn);
    }
}

print_r(array_unique($result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the various object arrays and merge them into one:

```
$syn = array();

foreach($synonyms as $o) {
    $syn = array_merge($syn, $o->syn);
}
```

Now just use `$syn`.

Answer (score 0):

An iterator would work here.

```
$originalArray = array('one', 'two', array('three'), array(array('four')));

// Iterate over the original and save to a new flattened array
$flattenedArray =  iterator_to_array(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
new RecursiveArrayIterator($originalArray)), FALSE);
print_r($flattenedArray);
```

Gives you:

```
Array
(
  [0] => one
  [1] => two
  [2] => three
  [3] => four
)
```